# Jack and Audio control out of sync studio 19.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack

After suffering many X runs in Mixbus 6 on Studio 19, I decided to take a look under the hood.

In case you don't have it, Studio 19.10  has a thing called Audio controls, and this controls jack and all sound cards. I fired up Qjackctl and found it was set to 44k and 3 buffers. The Audio Control was telling me it was 48K.

So MB6 is running in 48k as it should but jack was seeing 44k, hence something is amiss with the Audio control in Ubuntu studio.

I thought Audio Control was  a front end for Jack. Any ideas?

Comment: There's no Studio 19 in Ubuntu: Do you have Ubuntu Studio 19.04, or Ubuntu Studio 19.10, so some other distro? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Hi All  Today I had a major lock up and had to power cycle the PC. Not done this in a long time. I Have been using Harrison Mixbus 6 on studio18 and now 19.10.

Comment: I  don't know about `Audio Control`, what is that? Do you mean `Ubuntu Studio Controls`?